# How do I get the sum of the user input and a randomly generated number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started coding a month ago for school and we're currently finishing up our first project. I'm making a calculator of sorts that takes a user input(from 1-999), then generates a random number from 1-999, and then adds both together. Everything goes smoothly until it reaches the last few lines of code. Unfortunately, I can't quite get the final sum to show up in the console. I've tried so many things and I don't know what else to do anymore, just seems impossible.

Here's the code:

```
def click_circle(event):
    if event.key == "e":
       input_num = input("Type a number from 1 to 999. ")
       print("Your number is " + str(input_num) +  ".")
       print("I will now choose a number at random from 1 to 999, and add them.")
       final_random = random_number()
       final_random
       print("+")
       final = int(input_num) 
       print(final)
       print("Press R to add these two numbers.")
    if event.key == "r":
       print(sum(final, final_random))

   
add_key_down_handler(click_circle)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure on what it's asking but I guess you can do this?

```
import random

def click_circle(event):
    if event.key == "e":
        input_num = int(input('Type a number from 1  to 999. '))
        print(f'Your number is {input_num}.')

        print('I will now choose a number at random from 1 to 999, and add them.')
        final_random = random.randint(1,999)
        print(input_num)
        final_process = input('Press R to add these two numbers.')
        if event.key == 'r':
            print(str(input_num + final_random))
```

or you can simplify everything and just do

```
import random

input_num = int(input('Type a number from 1  to 999. '))
random_num = random.randint(1,999)
print(input_num + random_num)
```

Comment: Thank you! This just saved me

Answer (score 0):

Sum takes an iteratable (list). so either: use sum([final, final_random]) or just use print(final + final_random)